# Fragment Activity Display Back Button

Tags: java, android, android-fragmentactivity, back-button

I search to know how to display back button in a class which inherit from FragmentActivity,

```
public class GoogleMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

I know there is the method onBackPressed() which can be override but i don't know how to display back button

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

I tried this method : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43976262/7079226 but it doesn't work,
Thanks for your answers

Comment: where do you wanna show the backbutton ?

Comment: try using this in onCreate() getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: i wanna to display an action bar but i don't know if a FragmentActivity can have one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have same problem with you. I already use `((AppCompatActivity)getApplicationContext()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` but always getting force close.
Then my solution is create my own toolbar in the layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/overflow_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:srcCompat="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/overflow_back"
            android:paddingLeft="32dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/overflow_back"
            android:text="Toolbar Title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


</RelativeLayout> </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

`overflow_back` for `backbutton`, `textToolbar` for `title`. 
In your activity:

```
imageBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

and for back button to work.. use this :-

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

         int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == android.R.id.home) {

           super.onBackPressed();

           return true;
        }

       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

   }
```

Comment: getSupportActionBar() is unknown by FragmentActivity

Comment: then use `getActivty().getSupportQctionBar();`

Comment: getActivity doesn't exist too, there is getActionBar() but its null in onCreate

Comment: i am updating the answer please check

Comment: Thx Santanu but it doesn't work too, i used the solution to create my own action bar, thanks

Comment: @SedjiAka your solution will work too.. but mine will also work .. you have missed somthing then..